# Add a PostLinkTypes table to SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

The `PostLinks` table in SEDE has a column called `LinkTypeId`, but there's nothing in the schema that describes what various values of `LinkTypeId` mean. For I think all of the other "Type" columns, there are corresponding description tables like `CloseReasonTypes` and `PostHistoryTypes` and `ReviewTaskTypes`.

So, it would be nice if we had a new table called `PostLinkTypes`. I guess it would just have two columns (`Id tinyint` and `Name nvarchar`), and probably only two rows, too, seeing as the only values of `LinkTypeId` I've found are `1` (regular links) and `3` (links to duplicates).

Motivation: I looked at the `PostLinks` table for the first time in the process of writing [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/265721/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures) and had to spelunk through the table to figure out what the `LinkTypeId` column meant.

Comment: I also think this would be worth adding. It's easy enough to find [documentation on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), but the lack of `i` info button is a bit inconsistent and mildly inconvenient, as is the lack of an automatic look up of descriptive names for ids for generating reports (still an easy workaround, of course). I'm a big fan of self-documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The two values you found are the only ones:

### PostLinks

- `Id` primary key
- `CreationDate` when the link was created
- `PostId` id of source post
- `RelatedPostId` id of target/related post
- `LinkTypeId`  type of link
  1. Linked
  3. Duplicate

Until the feature request gets implemented you could [setup the table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/265891/postlinktypes-temporary-table) your self (but a simple `case when` construction is less trouble)

```sql
/* setup the missing PostLinkTypes table 
   as a temporary table */
create table #PostLinkTypes(
id  integer,
name nvarchar(200))

/* fill table with lookup values */
insert into #PostLinkTypes values (1,'Linked');
insert into #PostLinkTypes values (3,'Duplicate');

/* end setup */

select top 100
       PostId as [Post Link]
      , RelatedPostId as [Post Link] 
      , plt.Name
      , case 
        when pl.linktypeid = 1 then 'Linked'
        when pl.linktypeid = 3 then 'Duplicate'  
        end as [alternative]
from PostLinks pl
inner join #PostLinkTypes plt on plt.id = pl.linktypeid
where plt.id = pl.linktypeid
order by creationdate desc
```

You can always check the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) for explanation of tables, fields and content.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, there are a ton of workarounds; the main reason I see for having the table in SEDE itself is so that you have the little "i" button for the table in the right pane of the editor so that you can easily view the list of link types.